# Does it make sense to use a Textbox for a control that functions as a Label in an SSRS Report?

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder, rdl

I am modifying an existing SSRS report (*.rdl). Even for how klunky and kludgy the modification of these reports seems to be, it seems exceedingly macabre to me that a control that is simply used as a label is, in fact, a Textbox.

Is this just a vagary of this particular report (the previous developer used a Textbox because he didn't know better) or is it really so that Textboxes are typically used as Labels on SSRS reports?

The only types of controls listed in the entire Properties list of the .rdl are:

```
Image
Matrix (which, until now, I thought was a movie)
Textbox
Rectangle
```

Is there really such a dearth of control types available in SSRS (.rdl) reports?

Comment: I'm not sure what your understanding of a "textbox" is, but it seems like you are comparing report design to something like designing a Windows Forms UI. These things are not comparable despite appearances, in Reporting Services if you need to put some text on a report, whether it is for a label, a title or a description, you use a textbox.

Comment: Okay, got it; still seems odd, though; you may as well make that an answer so I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my earlier comment, the answer is yes this does make sense. In Reporting Services the method for adding any kind of text to a report is the [Textbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239366.aspx) control. This is used for labels, titles, descriptions and also the contents of each cell in a table or matrix.